# Cheap Dual Link DVI to DisplayPort Adapter 144Hz

Tags: monitors, video-adapters

### Background

I'm owner of a Mac Pro (late 2013), and I recently bought a BenQ XL2411Z as primary monitor, and my "old" Mac Monitor as secondary one.

I bought also the BenQ because I wanted a better monitor (in terms of fluidity, and response time) for playing.
So I chose this one for these things: 144Hz refresh rate & 1ms response time.

But there's a problem, I can't select 144Hz because I have the Single Link Adapter, so it works, but it's like the cable was a Single Link.

I saw the Apple Dual Link to DisplayPort Adapter, it seems that chasing a Dual Link DVI to Mini Displayport is the only solution, but it's like really expensive: $100 for the adapter.

### Requirements

I need a low cost but reliable way to connect my Mac Pro to the BenQ XL2411Z so that it functions at the native resolution and refresh rate. The adapter has to be

- Reasonably priced
- Support the ports found on the Mac Pro (late 2013) and the BenQ XL2311Z
- Able to function at the BenQ monitor's native resolution (1920x1080 @ 144Hz)

Comment: There are a couple of things you need to do for us to be able to answer. Firstly, we answer product recommendations, not website recommendations. Secondly, you need to have specific requirements of the product in mind so that we can narrow down the field for you.

Comment: I've listed your requirements more explicitly, which should get it reopened sooner. Is there any reason you can't use the HDMI port? I believe the [Mac Pro in question](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202801) and the [BenQ monitor](http://www.benq.com.au/product/monitor/xl2411z/specifications/) both support HDMI I/O

Comment: @Alpha3031 Apparently, HDMI doesn't support more than 60Hz refresh.

Comment: Oh. Right, my mistake. The BenQ XL2411Z doesn't support HDMI 1.3, so DVI-D is the only option :/

Comment: Alright, I'm using DVI-S apparently, but I have a dual link. I'm just searching for the adapter from DVID to Mini Display port. I guess Apple's one is the only one I can find.